# How to select multiple files using jquery multifile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jquery multifile upload control http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/.
I am able to select multiple images one by one. But I also want to select multiple images at once when the user hits the browse button. Is there any workaround using jquery multifile control?

Answer (score 4):

Our plugin now supports HTML5, so...

1. users can select multiple files one-at-a time in xHTML and <= HTML4
2. users can select multiple files at once in HTML5 with the "multiple" attribute

Checkout the new version of the plugin here:
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile

And if you want to help us improve the plugin, fork us here:
http://github.com/fyneworks/multifile

Comment: (For future readers: for a moment this looked quite spammy to me, but then I saw that this question is actually about this plugin.)

Comment: Sorry if it looked spammy, I'm new to stackoverflow (long-time reader, first time poster). But it really isn't spam tho, I just released a HTML5-compatible version of our plugin so I thought it would be best to find some of the old requests for this feature and let the users know :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there isn't (fyneworks website says you can't select multiple files at once), you can use HTML5 multiple tag or try this [plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 allows the user to select multiple files and therefore bypasses the need for the jQuery plugin.